# Access Select query with multiple "and" in Detail

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Access DB with this tables:
(Sorry, i´m very new to stackoverflow and cant add this picture directly)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLJhY.png

The data come from word documents. I have multiple page names and contentcontrols (table CCInfo)

If i start a query (created with Access):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DokInfo.*
FROM
SeitenName INNER JOIN (
(DokInfo INNER JOIN Hilfstabelle_Seiten ON DokInfo.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seiten.DokInfoID) 
INNER JOIN (CCInfo INNER JOIN Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC ON CCInfo.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC.CCInfoID) 
ON Hilfstabelle_Seiten.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC.Hilfstabelle_SeitenID) 
ON SeitenName.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seiten.SeitenNameID
WHERE  ((CCInfo.CCName)="Land") AND ((CCInfo.Inhalt)="Deutschland")
```

I can get all records from DokInfo, that has in the Detail table (CCInfo) rows with the search words.

If i change the WHERE to:

```
WHERE  (
((CCInfo.CCName)="Land") AND ((CCInfo.Inhalt)="Deutschland") 
OR 
((CCInfo.CCName)="Land") AND ((CCInfo.Inhalt)="Frankreich")
)
```

That works well.

But how can i search for "Land = Deutschland" and "Artikel = Schraube"?
If i try it with:

```
WHERE  (
((CCInfo.CCName)="Land") AND ((CCInfo.Inhalt)="Deutschland") 
AND 
((CCInfo.CCName)="Artikel") AND ((CCInfo.Inhalt)="Schraube")
)
```

i get no results. I think that is right. I have no "one" Data-Row with both results.

I have found that this can be done with intersect in SQL. But how can i do it in Access (2010)? All examples I could find, I could not switch to my case.

Later i want implement it in an vb.net projekt to create querys dynamically on user input. Is it perhaps be better if i query to different tables and make the evaluation of the tables in the program?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

After a few tests i have found a way...but so the results are not correct:

```
select DokInfo.ID, DokInfo.Maschinennummer
FROM 
 (
      SELECT DokInfo.ID, DokInfo.Maschinennummer
      FROM
      SeitenName INNER JOIN ((DokInfo INNER JOIN Hilfstabelle_Seiten ON DokInfo.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seiten.DokInfoID) INNER JOIN (CCInfo INNER JOIN Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC ON CCInfo.ID =                     Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC.CCInfoID) ON Hilfstabelle_Seiten.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC.Hilfstabelle_SeitenID) ON SeitenName.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seiten.SeitenNameID
      WHERE
      (
      ((CCInfo.CCName)="Land") AND ((CCInfo.Inhalt)="Frankreich") 
      OR
      ((CCInfo.CCName)="Artikel") AND ((CCInfo.Inhalt)="Schraube")
      )
 ) 

 GROUP BY DokInfo.ID, DokInfo.Maschinennummer
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

If one of these conditions have more than one row (for example there where two elements with "CCName = Land" and "Inhalt = "Frankreich") the count(*) is = 3

If i use UNION it seems to be working:

```
select DokInfo.ID, DokInfo.Maschinennummer
FROM 
 (
      SELECT DISTINCT DokInfo.*
      FROM
      SeitenName INNER JOIN ((DokInfo INNER JOIN Hilfstabelle_Seiten ON DokInfo.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seiten.DokInfoID) INNER JOIN (CCInfo INNER JOIN Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC ON CCInfo.ID =                     Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC.CCInfoID) ON Hilfstabelle_Seiten.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC.Hilfstabelle_SeitenID) ON SeitenName.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seiten.SeitenNameID
      WHERE  ((CCInfo.CCName)="Land") AND ((CCInfo.Inhalt)="Deutschland")
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT DokInfo.*
      FROM
      SeitenName INNER JOIN ((DokInfo INNER JOIN Hilfstabelle_Seiten ON DokInfo.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seiten.DokInfoID) INNER JOIN (CCInfo INNER JOIN Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC ON CCInfo.ID =           Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC.CCInfoID) ON Hilfstabelle_Seiten.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seite_CC.Hilfstabelle_SeitenID) ON SeitenName.ID = Hilfstabelle_Seiten.SeitenNameID
      WHERE  ((CCInfo.CCName)="Artikel") AND ((CCInfo.Inhalt)="Schraube")
 ) 
 GROUP BY DokInfo.ID, DokInfo.Maschinennummer
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

But i think this is very slow? It has the advantage that i can simply create the command string in vb.net. even a multi-AND-OR-query is then possible.

```
select DokInfo.ID, DokInfo.Maschinennummer
FROM 
 (
      SELECT DISTINCT DokInfo.*
      FROM
      [....]
      WHERE  [....]
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT DokInfo.*
      FROM
      [....]
      WHERE  [....]
 ) 
 GROUP BY DokInfo.ID, DokInfo.Maschinennummer
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
UNION
select DokInfo.ID, DokInfo.Maschinennummer
FROM 
 (
      SELECT DISTINCT DokInfo.*
      FROM
      [....]
      WHERE  [....]
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT DokInfo.*
      FROM
      [....]
      WHERE  [....]
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT DokInfo.*
      FROM
      [....]
      WHERE  [....]
 ) 
 GROUP BY DokInfo.ID, DokInfo.Maschinennummer
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

But is this a way that could i use for those querys?

Comment: there is a typo in second WHERE, change middle AND to OR. Resulting condition: WHERE  (
((CCInfo.CCName)="Land") AND ((CCInfo.Inhalt)="Deutschland") 
OR 
((CCInfo.CCName)="Artikel") AND ((CCInfo.Inhalt)="Schraube")
)

Comment: When i change the AND to OR the result are all lines. But i want only datarows from DokInfo that has both. Sorry, my english is bad to explain exactly.